# Issue in sum function for ORC hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

I have a hive table stored as ORC having a `bigint` column `col1` and many other columns.

Few records of `col1` :

```
3180231637038089849
3185739118697487865
3196698142218730052
3262542509863274723
3180231637038089849
3262542509863274723
3180231637038089849
```

I need to calculate *sum* of `col1` values. As the sum will be greater than the max value, So I am casting it to decimal(38,0)

```
select sum(cast(col1 as decimal (38,0))) from sample_table;
```

Execption:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) [Error getting row data with exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:198)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:184)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:239)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
 ]
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.process(GroupByOperator.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:235)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:314)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:98)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.updateAggregations(GroupByOperator.java:587)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:851)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:695)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.process(GroupByOperator.java:761)
    ... 8 more
```

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample-table`(
  `col2` bigint, 
  `col1` bigint)
CLUSTERED BY ( 
  col2) 
INTO 2 BUCKETS
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'hdfs://mycluster:8020/apps/hive/warehouse/testdb.db/sanple-table'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'last_modified_by'='devender', 
  'last_modified_time'='1521526039', 
  'numFiles'='1', 
  'numRows'='0', 
  'rawDataSize'='0', 
  'totalSize'='49939', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1521526106')
```

*There are around 130 columns there.*

**This query is working fine if I create textfile table and run the query on that table.**

```
create table sample_table_text stored as textfile as select * from sample_table;
```

Comment: Why is the stacktrace saying it's parsing JSON? Please show your table definition

Comment: unable to replicate in Hive 1.1.0, what hive version are you using? did you try casting to bigint?

Comment: @hlagos my hive version is 1.2.1. values are around 1/3rd of BigInt's MAX value. CASTing to bigint will cause overflow. Did you try with ORC table?

Comment: @cricket_007 I added the result of `show create table` script in the question.

Comment: @devツ sorry, unable to replicate at least with the sample data. I just created a textfile table with the sample and another table in orc, couldnt replicate it.

Comment: Thanks, @hlagos. I created a separate table with only 1 column and its working. Maybe I am missing something or clustering or bucketing has to do something with it.

Comment: how did you create the orc data in this case? maybe there is an issue with the data itself